# How can I use a 3d array of indices for a 2d array slicing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-slicing

I have 2 arrays as input. On array as output. Array `a` holds the data and is of shape `(N,M)`, while array `b` holds the indices and is of shape `(N,X,2)`. The resulting array should be of shape `(N,X)`, with the values taken from `a`.

Right now it only works with a for loop. How could I vectorize it since I have huge arrays as input?

Below is a sample code to demonstrate what I have right now:

```py
import numpy as np

# a of shape (N,M)
# b of shape (N,X,2)
# t_result of shape (N, X)

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 10))
b = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 9, 2))

t_result = np.empty((10, 9))

for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    t_result[i] = a[i, b[i, :, 0]]

print(t_result)
print(t_result.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I adapted a bit the answer to another [post from scleronomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156337/numpy-indexing-with-list-of-lists):

```py
import numpy as np

# a of shape (N,M)
# b of shape (N,X,2)
# t_result of shape (N, X)

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 10))
b = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 9, 2))

t_result = np.empty((10, 9))

t_result = a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],b[np.arange(b.shape[0]),:,0]]

print(t_result)
print(t_result.shape)
```

I am not sure whether or not it is the best solution but it works.